# Typescript: Override static method of generic class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Given a template class: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAQwRgzgLgTiDGUAE8A2IISUgsgewBMBTVAHgBUA%20JAb2G2wAcBXMVAS3iWhCk5RhFeRCkiIAPKEQB2BLAHJ8xVPMoAKegy1QAFuwgAuWkmlEA7kjUBKI%20SQBfJADIkUAJ6MieAGa5CJABpNLWwANxBUZiIIAH4jPDAAKyJEYKQbJAAFGDwAW30RKjoQhng8aQg8VCIAOlQ8AHM1cMjoqwBuNK1BKGYYaVpHDCyc-IhCynakAHpppB0EAGsamrT7TvtgYHdPJAB5aVQ3AEEoWAgKagBeWjSAbQBpJHYB4pKkR%20eBxaI3HyRyABdWyPQFiSQyOSWFY1EAwBqGJDMaSLaR4MzSO6AqxIK7UZGo9EDGImIihIgwJBGB6dLT2O4-P6%20IGAuIA0EbTrACSMPAwZDgaBwRAodCYJAAIQwRCUJEu4KksiwsrIVFuaQwBAAhLYuVoeHwuPBBMJRBJFVCVZd1C1DAcjqdzpccUZsnkCpc3iUen0BhBmJ4YDVjUIpM0IhArGtgJsgA)

```
abstract class  Model<T> {
    public static create<T extends 'Model'>(
        this: { new (): T } & typeof Model,
        values?: object
    ): Promise<T>{
        console.log(values);
        return {} as Promise<T>; // hack..
    };
}

type OnlyAttrs<T> = {
    [K in {
        [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown ? never : K;
    }[keyof T]]?: T[K];
};

export abstract class BaseModel<T> extends Model<T> {

    asd!: T;

    static create<T extends Model<T>>(vals:OnlyAttrs<T>) : Promise<T>{
        return super.create(vals) // ##### How to make this work!? #####
    }
}
```

how can I override the static super create method of a generic class?

This example is taken from Sequelize, in an attempt to make the create method strongly typed with `OnlyAttrs<T>`